# IntelliJ Idea 12, Incompatibile SDK Tools package

Tags: android, sdk, intellij-idea

I am writing my first android application and after constructing two basic views in IntelliJ 11 I was advised to switch to 12 for the visual Designer tool.

I have loaded the existing project into IntelliJ 12 and when I try to run it on an AVD I get the following error

"android-validator: [PanPlan] Incompatible version of Android SDK Tools package. Min version is 19. Please, update it though SDK manager"

When I open the SDK manager however it seems I have the latest Tools package:

[image]

The project structure

[image]

As per @ekudel's suggestion, attaching contents of /android-sdk-macosx/tools/source.properties

```
Pkg.UserSrc=false
Pkg.Revision=22.0.5
Platform.MinPlatformToolsRev=18
```

Comment: What is the exact IDEA 12 version you are using? Do you have the same problem with IDEA [12.1.5 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP) or [13 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP)?

Comment: It's 12.1.4 at the moment, (installed yesterday). You think I should download the EAP?

Comment: Try to restart IDEA. Also make sure that correct SDK path is configured in the IDE.

Comment: I've restarted IntelliJ and the computer many times. I added a screenshot of the project structure and the SDK path is the same.

Comment: Could you attach .../android-sdk-macosx/tools/source.properties file? This is the file IDEA looks at to check the package version.

Comment: Done. It does show Platform.MinPlatformToolsRev=18 so that must be causing the problem. but why does the manager say something else?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. The IDE looks at Pkg.Revision only and it seems to be correct

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it with simple new "Hello, world" project?

Comment: Then I get "Android Packager: Cannot run program "/Users/Nieszka/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/tools/zipalign": error=1, Operation not permitted" :/

Comment: Had this before, when I try to run zipalign manually I get the annoying "this app is downloaded from the internet. are you sure you want to run it?" When I click yes and try to rebuild in intelliJ I get similar errors about other processes. Currently trying to figure out how to mark the contents of the whole folder as safe so I can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I found after days of struggling is far from perfect and I'm willing to accept a different answer should one appear. Hopefully anyone struggling with the same problem will find this useful.

1. I found no way of importing the old project to work in IntelliJ Idea 12
2. I had to disable the mac warning for downloaded applications for the android-sdk-macosx folder. (Using [this guide](http://osxdaily.com/2010/09/12/disable-application-downloaded-from-the-internet-message-in-mac-os-x/).)
3. I had to manually copy/paste code and resources from the old project.
4. This only worked if I selected the 4.2.2 as the platform, selecting 4.0.3 led to the same
   ""android-validator: [PanPlan] Incompatible version of Android SDK Tools package. Min version is 19. Please, update it though SDK manager" error.